# running mutliple worker in parallel in gearman-python

Tags: python, gearman, python-gearman

I have 5 workers doing different tasks and i am passing the same input to all the 5 workers and retrieving the collective output of all the 5 workers.

I am using [gearman](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gearman/) library of python and i have tried using

```
 m_client.submit_multiple_jobs(site, background=False, wait_until_complete=False)
```

Now i need to make sure that all these 5 workers are working in parallel.
How can i achieve it ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with "make sure the all these 5 workers are running in parallel". Anyway, do not use python_gearman since it is no longer supported. There is a new python library https://github.com/Yelp/pygear which works better and uses a more updated version of the gearman protocol.